# Including Custom Modules in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node/Express and I'm not entirely sure where things go...

I want to have a little custom class - where do I put this custom code in my express app? I seem to have to put it inside "node_modules" for it to be picked up by require which isn't really what I want. Ideally I'd like to have it in a lib folder or the likes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you had a Person class like this in `lib/person`:

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};
```

You can export this using node's `module.exports` like this (in `lib/person`):

```
module.exports = Person;
```

To use the person class you would then do:

```
var Person = require('./lib/person');   
var jim = new Person('jim');
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. I tried this... is it still './lib/person' if you are calling require from /routes/index.js? It can't seem to find it.

Comment: That's it, glad I could help!